# Taylor series of $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z-2}$ at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following question. I know that 
$$e^z=\sum \frac{z^{n}}{n!}$$
What is the Taylor series of $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z-2}$ at $z=0$? What is the convergence radius?

Answer (score 2):

We have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{z-2}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}}=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{2^n}\ \text{for}\ |z/2|<1.
\end{equation}
Now you can use Cauchy product rule to find product of $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{2^n}$ for $|z|<2$.